# Ratio on Vbat measurement STM32F303

Tags: stm32

This question might possibly be answered somewhere, but as I'm googling the particular phrase in the title, I couldn't find anything. I'm fairly new to designing development boards. I use the [STM32F303](http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/2308889.pdf) and came across a certain description in the manual that I don't understand.

[image: STM32F303]

I want to connect my battery with the V_Bat pin of the STM32 and I don't understand what is meant by the second line "Ratio on V_Bat measurement: 2". Can please somebody explain this to me with a possible circuit example. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is described in the datasheet, in the battery voltage monitoring chapter.

The battery voltage can be higher than VDDA used for the ADC so it could be out of range, so battery voltage has a voltage divider that divides the voltage by 2 for ADC measurement.

It means that your ADC measurement is half of actual battery voltage.